# curl command line vs HttpURLConnection API service call response time differences

Tags: java, performance, web-services, curl, httpconnection

I am consuming a web services using HttpURLConnection which took 60 seconds to return the response but when I use CURL(command line) for same operation with same parameters then it took only 20 - 25 seconds to return the response.

what could be the issue in API service call through HttpURLConnection because it's taking longer time to return the response.

HttpURLConnection API call code :

`

```
        url = new URL(this._serviceURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml;");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "http://www.xxtest.com/Request");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(xmlRequest);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        // Get Response
        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        String xmlResponse = "";
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success

            is = connection.getInputStream();
            xmlResponse = IOUtils.toString(is);
            // Decode base64 and Decompress
            final GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(xmlResponse.getBytes())));
            xmlResponse = IOUtils.toString(gzipInputStream);
        }`
```

CURL command :

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -H "SOAPAction: http://www.xxtest.com/Request" -H "Accept: application/xml;" -d @request_soap.xml 'http://www.xxtest.com/xmlservices.asmx' > response.xml
```

**Update :**
Above mentioned HttpURLConnection API call java code - when executed from a Web Application (Tomcat) then it's taking longer time(60 seconds) to return the response but when I run the same java code as standalone java program on same server then it is returning response in 20 seconds. Exactly same code. Now, I don't understand why the same code is taking longer time when it is getting executed from a Web Application.

Comment: Can you also show how you read the response? Maybe something is happening there.

Comment: @adhesivee InputStream to xmlResponse string conversion takes hardly 1 second to 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The performance problem might be at this point

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(xmlRequest);
wr.close();
```

I would guess following will get better Performance.

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(xmlRequest);
out.close();
```

Comment: I was using Axis client Stub based API service call there also I was facing delayed response issue so I have made changes and implemented HttpURLConnection to consume API services. My concern is if CURL can receive response in 20 seconds then why Stub based API service call & HttpURLConnection API service call taking around 60 seconds. If there is network issue then CURL should also take time but that's not happening. I will implement your suggestion and will update here.

Comment: @Santosh Maybe you should first try to isolate the part which where the delay happen. My answer is more or less a educated guess. And I would normally not assume that is will be three times slower.

Answer (score 1):

I have added Proxy.NO_PROXY in openConnection method in a HttpURLConnection API call code(mentioned in my question) and delayed response issue solved. The services which I was consuming were having proxy setting and because of that I was facing delayed response issue.
Please check below mentioned code snippet.

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
```